# Claire North - The Gameshouse - Does this piece represent luck?

Tags: symbolism, claire-north, the-gameshouse

In [*The Gameshouse*](https://www.kategriffin.net/books/the-gameshouse-novellas/) by Claire North (A.K.A. [Catherine Webb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine_Webb)) two things occur:

In 'The Serpent':

> The player, Thene, has a 'roman coin' that she uses when an opposition piece ( her husband, Jacamo de Orcelo ) is about to assassinate her 'king' or main piece. This causes Jacamos gun to backfire, thus preventing the assassination and killing Jacamo instead.

In 'The Master':

> Right at the end when all the pieces have been played and Silver and the Gamesmaster are alone, instead of shooting the Gamesmaster, Silver 'Flips' the roman coin. Throughout the last gasps of the book, the Gamesmaster implores Silver not to flip the coin.

SO (the question):

> Does the roman coin represent 'luck' ? In 'The Serpent' a misfiring gun can only be explained by luck (good for the player, bad for the husband). In 'The Master' it is explained that they're playing chess (albeit on a worldwide scale) and, in chess, luck plays no part.